# Comparing ndarray derived classes

Tags: python, numpy

Following the instructions [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.subclassing.html#slightly-more-realistic-example-attribute-added-to-existing-array) I created a subclass of ndarray that adds new attributes to the ndarray class. Now I want to define a comparison operator for the new class that besides comparing the data, also compares the values of the attributes. So I tried this:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return (self._prop1 == other._prop1) and \
           (self._prop2 == other._prop2) and \
           (self.data == other.data)
```

This allows for comparison like `T1 == T2` and returns a boolean value. However since I would like to use these arrays interchangeably with other ndarrays I would like the comparison to return a boolean array. If I don't define my `__eq__` function then the comparison returns a boolean array, but then I can't check for the attributes. How can I combine the two?

Comment: Looks like `ndarray` returns scalar True/False if attributes (e.g. shape) don't match, and the boolean array only if they all match.  With one or `ifs` you should be able to return your attribute tests if they fail, and `else` return the `data` test.  Allow yourself multiple `returns`.  It's easier to write code that way.

Comment: @hpaulj separating the comparison of my custom attributes and the underlying data is a nice suggestion. However, the problem is still that the comparison of the data attributes itself returns a boolean, not an array. How can I call numpy's element-wise comparison from my comparison operator?

Comment: Take a look at how masked array handles this: `np.ma.core.MaskedArray.__eq__`

Answer (score 2):

As per the [suggestion by hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34073904/comparing-ndarray-derived-classes#comment55902177_34073904) I figured out how to do this by looking at `np.ma.core.MaskedArray.__eq__`. Here's the minimum implementation for reference. The main idea is to call the numpy `__eq__()` on a view of `self` in the type of the base class of `DerivedArray`.

```
class DerivedArray(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, input_array, prop1, prop2):       
        _baseclass = getattr(input_array, '_baseclass', type(input_array))
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)

        obj._prop1    = prop1
        obj._prop2    = prop2
        obj._baseclass = _baseclass
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None:
            return
        else:
            if not isinstance(obj, np.ndarray):
                _baseclass = type(obj)
            else:
                _baseclass = np.ndarray

        self._prop1    = getattr(obj, '_prop1', None)
        self._prop2    = getattr(obj, '_prop2', None)
        self._baseclass= getattr(obj, '_baseclass', _baseclass)

    def _get_data(self):
        """Return the current data, as a view of the original
        underlying data.
        """
        return np.ndarray.view(self, self._baseclass)

    _data = property(fget=_get_data)
    data  = property(fget=_get_data)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        attsame = (self._prop1 == other._prop1) and (self._prop2 == other._prop2)
        if not attsame: return False
        return self._data.__eq__(other)
```